# Sum of Random Variables, Conditional on One Being Larger than the other

Tags: integration, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, bayesian

I'm trying to learn about the sum of $ii$ random variables, conditional on a few of them being larger than the others.

Suppose I have four random variables, all drawn iid from the same absolutely continuous distribution $F$. Call them: $\theta^{A}_{1}, \theta^{A}_{2}, \theta^{B}_{1}$ and $\theta^{B}_{2}$.

I'm trying to derive the probability the sum of the 1st and 3rd are greater than the sum of the 2nd/4th, conditional on 1 being greater than two. That is:

$$\Pr(\theta^{A}_{1}+\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{A}_{2}+\theta^{B}_{1} | \theta^{A}_{1}>\theta^{A}_{2})$$

Everything in the summations is $iid$, although of course it's not $iid$ once we condition on $\theta^{A}_{1}>\theta^{A}_{2}$.

I'm not sure how to proceed, including what general toolkit to use. I could use Bayes theorem, but this seems like it would create another conditional probability in the numerator.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using those symbols rather than just $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3,$ and $\theta_4$?  Or possibly $A_1, A_2, B_1,$ and $B_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Let it be:
$A=\Pr(\theta^{A}_{1}+\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{A}_{2}+\theta^{B}_{1})$
$B=\Pr(\theta^{A}_{1}+\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{A}_{2}+\theta^{B}_{1}\cap\theta^{A}_{1}>\theta^{A}_{2})$
$C=\Pr(\theta^{A}_{1}+\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{A}_{2}+\theta^{B}_{1}\cap\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{B}_{1})$
$D=\Pr(\theta^{A}_{1}+\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{A}_{2}+\theta^{B}_{1}\cap\theta^{A}_{1}>\theta^{A}_{2}\cap\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{B}_{1})$
Evidently:
$A=B+C-D,\quad B=C,\quad A=1/2,\quad D=1/4$
Then:
$B=C=3/8$
And:
$\Pr(\theta^{A}_{1}+\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{A}_{2}+\theta^{B}_{1}\mid\theta^{A}_{1}>\theta^{A}_{2})=\frac{3/8}{1/2}=3/4$

Comment: It is very cool how you did that without making reference to the characteristics of the distribution $F$. I will have to study this closely!

Comment: I need some help understanding this answer. Why do we introduce $\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{B}_{1}$? This is not complementary to the $\theta^{A}_{1}>\theta^{A}_{2}$, because the letters are different. Was this a typo?

Comment: If $\quad\theta^{A}_{1}+\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{A}_{2}+\theta^{B}_{1}\quad$
or $\quad\theta^{A}_{1}>\theta^{A}_{2}\quad$
or $\quad\theta^{B}_{2}>\theta^{B}_{1}\quad$.